# How could I get list of PayPal stores(https://shopping.paypal.com/stores) by PayPal API?

Tags: api, paypal, html-parsing

How could I get list of PayPal stores(https://shopping.paypal.com/stores) by PayPal API?
Or i have to parse html page mentioned above by myself?